# How to make a JavaScript result appear on the same page, not in an alert popup window

Tags: javascript

I was wondering instead of using the alert function to show the function result if there was a way to print it in a text field on the same page as the original variable input. Thanks!

Comment: Using jquey you can do as $("#inputId").val(msg);

Comment: Without something more specific I assume your question roughly boils down to "can I modify the DOM on the current page", to which the answer is of course you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a div in your body for result like

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

update from script like

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
resultDiv.innerHTML = <your value>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without additional libraries, using only browser functions, you can do this with the `document.getElementById()` function like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="textfield">
</body>

<script>
    function someFunction() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    document.getElementById('textfield').value = someFunction();
</script>

<html>
```